# Asp.net WebApi : No type was found that matches the controller named 'xxxx'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this issue that seems quite common, but none of the solutions I've read about worked in my case. I'm trying to add an ApiController in an existing MVC project.

When I try to access the added controller on http://localhost:51362/api/test, I get this error: `{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51362/api/test'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'."}`

My project contains the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.2.3

My Global.asax.cs (excerpt):

```
RouteTable.Routes.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

My WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace End.Web
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My new controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace End.Web.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried attribute routing with no success. What I want to do seems really simple. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried to set `[HttpGet]` attribute for `Get()` action?

Comment: @Roma Web API v2 automatically maps the HTTP verb based on the name of the method - this should not be necessary

Comment: Can you double-check that your WebApiConfig.Register method is actually hit?

Comment: @Roma just tried [HttpGet], same result.

Comment: @Anestis Kivranoglou Just tried this URL, doesn't work either (same error).

Comment: @CoolBots if I put a breakpoint there, it is hit, and after I resume execution I get the error.

Comment: Not a solution, but a troubleshooting step - if you only leave `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` in `Application_Start` - does it work then? I am trying to see if the routes are being cleared or overwritten somehow after the `WebApiConfig.Register` runs...

Comment: @CoolBots good idea, but I get the same error message (I've also tried to remove other events such as Application_BeginRequest etc.). I'll try to clear my Web.config similarly, maybe there's something in there. EDIT: still the same error after cleaning Web.config (removed handlers, rewrites, and modules).

Comment: @youen try to add action to your 'routeTemplate' and also your 'url'. May be it can't detece your default action.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos I've changed the DefaultApi route with `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"`, renamed `public string Get()` to `public string something()`, and using the URL http://localhost:51362/api/test/something I still get the same error :(

Comment: @youen Are you sure don't not run any VPN or tunneling,etc application in your computer?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos yes, and I'm also sure I'm hitting the right web site because for example if I remove the call to WebApiConfig.Register, I get the regular MVC 404 error `The resource cannot be found` (instead of the API json response saying `No type was found that matches the controller`)

Comment: Can you try adding(or renaming Get to) a Index method, inside your test controller? make sure that method is public.

Comment: In which event of Global.asax you're calling GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); ??

Comment: @irvgk same error if I add `public string Index() { return "ok"; }` and use the URL `http://localhost:51362/api/test`

Comment: @AmanB in `Application_Start`

Comment: Is this solved? If not, Try and add [Route("api/test")] ontop of the method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old issue, but since it never got an accepted answer, I'll give it a go.

I had this exact issue as well. For me, this solved the issue:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
{
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver());
    ...
});
```

In my case, `WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver` was used instead of `DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver`. `WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver` first reads controller types from a cache (a file), and if that file exists, it's content is serialized and returned. If the file don't exist, `WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver` calls `DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver` instead.

I got the problem by first setting up the web api, but not having any API controllers. That resulted in a cached empty list of controller types, hence the issue. Since the controller types is cached within a file, its contents won't be deleted even though you restart your Web API.

Another solution could be to remove the file that stores the cached list of controller types. The file is called `MS-ApiControllerTypeCache.xml` and should be somewhere in the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`.

[WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs)

Comment: Well, I honestly have no idea if this was my issue too... I don't even remember for which project I had this issue in the first place :) But I'll accept your answer since this looks like it could very well be the same problem.